# Using BeautifulSoup to extract anchor tag values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to extract values from a site. The values are essentially search results, in this case pharmacies in a particular region. The source of the page I'm trying to extract from contains the following HTML:

```
<a id="body_BusinessSearchResultSummaryList_repBusinessList_lnkBusinessProfile_1" class="sr-item-link" href="http://www.mocality.co.ke/b/applegene-pharmacy/applegene/brooklyn/health-and-beauty-medical/_/airtime-chemist-cosmetics-medicine/d42f7388-3f9b-4a34-8971-dc6ae9692586?skw=pharmacys&amp;rcnt=10">Applegene Pharmacy</a>
```

the id of the anchor tag is incremented based on the results so the next one has a 2:

```
<a id="body_BusinessSearchResultSummaryList_repBusinessList_lnkBusinessProfile_2" class="sr-item-link" href="http://www.mocality.co.ke/b/natros-pharmacy/natrosoh/innercore/medical-services/_/_/0cfe6a11-7bee-41f8-8d2e-6a472557201f?skw=pharmacys&amp;rcnt=10">Natros Pharmacy</a>
```

I've used findAll('a') but that gives me all anchor tags.How can I use BeautifulSoup to parse this and extract the values of the specific anchor tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<a id="body_BusinessSearchResultSummaryList_repBusinessList_lnkBusinessProfile_1" class="sr-item-link" href="http://www.mocality.co.ke/b/natros-pharmacy/natrosoh/innercore/medical-services/_/_/0cfe6a11-7bee-41f8-8d2e-6a472557201f?skw=pharmacys&amp;rcnt=10">Natros Pharmacy</a>
<a id="body_BusinessSearchResultSummaryList_repBusinessList_lnkBusinessProfile_2" class="sr-item-link
" href="http://www.mocality.co.ke/b/natros-pharmacy/natrosoh/innercore/medical-services/_/_/0cfe6a11-
7bee-41f8-8d2e-6a472557201f?skw=pharmacys&amp;rcnt=10">Natros Pharmacy</a>'''
match = 'body_BusinessSearchResultSummaryList_repBusinessList_lnkBusinessProfile'

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt)
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        if a.has_key('id') and a['id'].startswith(match):
               print a['href'], a.contents
```

Comment: I tried your code,no result is returned and no error is displayed. Any idea why?

Comment: it works on those links exactly, try running my edit by itself

Comment: tried it, works..but in my case I'm parsing a web page so the returned HTML from the page contains much more than what I pasted. I only showed the part I wanted to parse and extract values. Can the same code work with a whole bunch of HTML preceding the anchor tags?

Comment: yep, as long as your findAll() includes those anchors in the results.

Comment: '.has_key' is deprecated. Use '.has_attr' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword arguments of `find`, which restrict the attributes:

```
find("a", id="whatever_1")
```

You can also call `find` with a (boolean) function:

```
def isRight(tag):
    return ...

findAll(isRight)
```